# video is downloading but not playing in browser

Tags: video, stream, video-player

on my server I have many videos, I can download them with their links,
and when I download them my desktop players can play these videos.
but my browser cant play them or its just sound while playing and screen is black,
here is link of one of my videos :
http://91.121.179.217/Apps/FootPlus/Videos/1.mp4

is it related to video codecs ?
I checked using https://mediaarea.net tool, and I found out that codecs are different, but strange thing is that these videos are not uploaded today to server and in past they all worked and played by browser without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update :
now I know what was my problem exactly !!!!
on my server I'd installed dumpio module for my apache, which log request and response data and video files size were big enough to make me trouble :D
and the reason why It got better after video optimization was that video file sizes got smaller.

I didn't find the exact answer to my question and the reason why after a period of time my videos stopped getting played in browsers,but  using following bash script I converted my videos and now they're working.

```
${FILE_PATH} = '/path/to/videos/directory'

list=`find ${FILE_PATH} -name "*.mp4"`
for file in ${list}
do
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    video_file="${filename%.*}"
    echo "${video_file}.mp4"
    ffmpeg -y -i "${video_file}.mp4" -vcodec libx264 -b:v 350000 -movflags +faststart "x${video_file}.mp4"

done


END=574


for i in $(seq 1 ${END}); do

    if [[ -f "./$i.mp4" && -f  "./x$i.mp4" ]]; then
        rm "${i}.mp4"
        mv "x${i}.mp4" "${i}.mp4"
    fi


done
```